# Expressing an expectation for an action

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Here's a sentence that expresses an expectation for an object:

> I've been expecting your email.

How would it work if it had to express an expectation for an action instead?

Would the following be correct:

> I've been expecting you to write me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been expecting you to {perform some action}

is perfectly correct.

As an aside: in British English you are more likely to say `write to me` than `write me`. I believe the converse applies in US English.

Comment: I thought it's correct but then Google showed no results for it - http://bit.ly/iXLLgl.

Comment: 6 results for http://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+have+been+expecting+you+to+write%22  13300 for http://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+am+expecting+you+to+write%22 35900 for  for http://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+was+expecting+you+to+write%22

Comment: Should I understand that the past simple tense is more appropriate in this case?

Comment: The simple past suggests you stopped waiting some time ago. "I have been waiting" is usually used when indicating some continuous range of time up to the near present or beyond.